# How to solve $u_x+\frac{1}{4}u_y-\frac{15}{4}u=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> How to solve $u_x+\frac{1}{4}u_y-\frac{15}{4}u=0$

So I have that $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{4}$ which implies $y=\frac{1}{4}x+c$

then $v'(x)=\frac{15}{4}v(x)$

So by separation of variables I get $v(x)=Ke^{\frac{15}{4}x}$, where $v(x)=u(x,\frac{1}{4}x+c)$

From here I'm not sure what to do. Do I have that $K$ is a function of $c$?

Then $K(c)=K(y-\frac{1}{4}x)$ and $u(x,y)=K(y-\frac{1}{4}x)e^{\frac{15}{4}x}$ as my general solution? I dont see why $K$ should be a function of C if it is however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $y-\frac{1}{4}x=c_1$ and $ue^{-\frac{15}{4}x}=c_2$, and we combine these two expressions to find the general solution, since the constants depend on each other (see [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2414123/method-of-characteristics-relationship-of-constants)).
So we have the general solution

$$u(x,y)=e^{\frac{15}{4}x}K\left(y-\frac{1}{4}x\right)$$

for an arbitrary function $K$, which is obtained using the boundary conditions.